# refresh data table every x second - jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I'm trying to refresh a data table I have every 2 seconds.

my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var user = '<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>';
jQuery('.js-dataTable-full-pagination-help').DataTable({


pagingType: "full_numbers",
columnDefs: [ { orderable: false, targets: [ 4 ] } ],
pageLength: 10,
lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 15, 20], [5, 10, 15, 20]],
dom: 'lfBrtip',
buttons: [
        'copy',
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            messageTop: 'report'
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            title: ' report.'
        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            messageTop: 'printed by - '+user,
            title : ' report',
            exportOptions: {
                      columns: [1, 2,3,4, 5 ]
                  }

        }
    ]


});

</script>
```

what i tried :

```
setInterval(refreshTable , 1000 );});
```

and I tried ajax.reload...

I get this error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I have an ajax code to add values to the DB and showing them in the data table .. I want to refresh the table every 2 seconds so when the user adds something it appears on the table immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error, setInterval takes as arguments function reference and time in miliseconds like this:

```
var datatables = ('.js-dataTable-full-pagination-help').datatables ({Your-configurations}); // keep a reference to datatables api.
setInterval(refreshTable ,1000);
```

Or you can pass an anonymous function as the first argument like this:

```
setInterval (function () {
    // Do some more stuff
    refreshTable ();
}, 1000);
```

Or even simpler:

```
setInterval (datatables.ajax.reload, 1000); // then you can delete the refreshTable function entirely.
```

Assuming you have function refreshTable on that scope:

```
function  refreshTable() {
     // this function will be called every second
     // run here the ajax reload according to Datatables api
     datatables.ajax.reload ();
}
```